# Pip3 not updating dependencies when installed in a specific path

Tags: ubuntu, pip, firebase-admin, python-3.9, urllib3

I am using pip to install `firebase-admin, requests==2.28.0, urllib3==1.26.7`.
I start installing `firebase-admin` which comes with `requests==2.31.0` and `urllib3==2.1.0`

What i am trying to achieve is to replace `requests` and `urllib3` from `firebase-admin` to my own versions

I have started with installing `urllib3` then `requests` and then installing `firebase-admin` which replaces my versions.

I have also tried installing `firebase-admin` first then installing `requests` then `urllib` but when i run `pip3 freeze` it keeps on updating to firebase's versions

Below is how i am installing

```
    >>> pip3 install firebase-admin -t layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
    >>> pip3 install requests==2.28.0 -t layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
    >>> pip3 install urllib3==1.26.7  -t layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

Below is how i am checking the versions with

```
pip3 freeze --path layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Below is my `pip3 freeze` results

```
root@3123948321b4:/# pip3 freeze --path layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/           
CacheControl==0.13.1
cachetools==5.3.2
certifi==2023.11.17
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==41.0.5
firebase-admin==6.2.0
google-api-core==2.14.0
google-api-python-client==2.108.0
google-auth==2.23.4
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.1
google-cloud-core==2.3.3
google-cloud-firestore==2.13.1
google-cloud-storage==2.13.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.6.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.61.0
grpcio==1.59.3
grpcio-status==1.59.3
httplib2==0.22.0
idna==3.4
msgpack==1.0.7
proto-plus==1.22.3
protobuf==4.25.1
pyasn1==0.5.1
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.8.0
pyparsing==3.1.1
requests==2.31.0
rsa==4.9
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==2.1.0
```

The funny thing is that when i install the dependencies globally and update them they are changing to my updated version but when trying to update to my -t path its not updating

I have tried below by using `--upgrade` and `--force-reinstall` but they are not working

```
pip3 install urllib3==1.26.7 -t layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ --force-reinstall

pip3 install urllib3==1.26.7 --upgrade -t layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/

pip3 install firebase-admin --ignore-installed -t layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

Comment: `--target` is mostly intended for `pip download`. If you want to install — use virtual environments.